# Reading and writing messages into MQ from WAS Liberty

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, spring-jms

We were trying to send MAP (java.util) using JMS template , but at the client side we are unable to read the message and during the server start up , spring boot @JMSListener complains with the following message , this works fine with WAS 7 but doesnt with WAS Liberty 8.5.5 , iam also including the code snippet and also the different message format's that we are receiving for the different versions of server . Did any thing changed in WAS Liberty ?

WAS LIBERTY - 7 -

```
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
2019-07-05T13:07:14.357-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-jms-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
2019-07-05T13:07:14.357-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 10 common frames omitted
2019-07-05T13:07:14.393-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-07-05 18:07:14.370 WARN 20 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
2019-07-05T13:07:14.394-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.aa.amps.base.task.finalize.BaseBowUpdateListener.receiveMessage(javax.jms.MapMessage)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message [ID:414d51204d454d5154433120202020205ccc4b2725acdc4c] from destination [null]
```

message is MAP

```
 jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {
                    @Override
                    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
                        message.setJMSReplyTo(null);
                        LOGGER.info("In BaseBowUpdateSender - send() message to AMPS-BASE QUEUE : {} ", message);
                        return message;
                    }
                });
```

WAS - LIBERTY message format

```
JMSMessage class: jms_text
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     ID:414d51204d454d5154433120202020205ccc4b272634ce4d
  JMSTimestamp:     1562784513140
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   null
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   true
    JMSXAppID: jar                         
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 193
    JMSXUserID: apmqstc     
    JMS_IBM_Character_Set: UTF-8
    JMS_IBM_Encoding: 273
    JMS_IBM_Format: MQSTR   
    JMS_IBM_MsgType: 8
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20190710
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 18483314
<map><elt name="trackType">03</elt><elt name="lastDefferDate">07/10/2019</elt><elt name="packageDesc ...
```

Expected message below

```
JMSMessage class: jms_map
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     ID:414d51204d454d5154433120202020205ccc4b272634404a
  JMSTimestamp:     1562783439854
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   queue://- INFO IS THERE 
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: WebSphere MQ Client for Java
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 1
    JMSXUserID: apmqstc     
    JMS_IBM_Character_Set: UTF-8
    JMS_IBM_Encoding: 273
    JMS_IBM_Format: MQSTR   
    JMS_IBM_MsgType: 8
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20190710
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 18303986
```

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in Liberty vs traditional WAS that would be relevant. The mesage content being shown would be generated by the client application which appears to be different in the two cases. The JMSXAppID in the expected output says `WebSphere MQ Client for Java` and the actual says `jar`. I would suggest checking the application sending the message is sending a JMS MapMessage.

Comment: Thank you , We indeed are sending MAP Messages but we are setting the targetClientId as 'mq' which actually adds mq related info with some  additional headers to the message , once the targetClientId is removed JMS Info is added and the messages are sent as JMSMapMessage (jms_map) etc. Issue is resolved

Comment: You should post a self answer to explain the steps to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere MQ messages are being put by my application(JMS application) to a queue. These messages are to be picked up by a jms application. I have misunderstood targetClientId option available thinking that the targetClientId needed to be mentioned as "mq" if the messages where we write is an MQ but its not the case .We need to set targetClientId as MQ only if we the messages are processed by non-jms application. As i was setting the targetClientId as 'MQ' its stripping the RFH headers needed for the JMS application to process the message and parsing fails at the consuming application .

```
        <jmsQueue id="MYAPP_QUEUE" jndiName="jms/test/testq">
            <properties.wmqJms 
                baseQueueName="MYAPP.TEST.A" 
                persistence="PERS" 
                targetClient="MQ"/> -- removed this 
        </jmsQueue>
```